# Как подключить SDL2?

Tags: c, sdl

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь подключить SDL2, но ничего не выходит.

ОС: `Win 10 x64`

IDE: `Dev-Cpp`

Compiler: `TDM-GCC-4.9.2 64-bit Release`

1. Создал папку `dev` для проекта
2. Скачал с официального сайта SDL2 архив `SDL2-devel-2.0.5-mingw.tar.gz`
3. Распаковал папку `i686-w64-mingw32`
4. Скопировал папку `include` в папку с проектом (в папку `dev`)
5. Скопировал файл `bin/SDL2.dll` в папку с проектом
6. Добавил `include/SDL2` в пути `C Includes`
7. Создал файл `main.c` с таким содержимым:

   ```
   #include <SDL.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
       SDL_Quit();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   8. Добавил `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows` к флагам компилятора.     Соответствующие библиотеки взял из архива `SDL2-devel-2.0.5-VC`.
   9. Лог компиляции:

```
Compiling single file...
--------
- Filename: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\main.c
- Compiler Name: TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

Processing C source file...
--------
- C Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe
- Command: gcc.exe "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\main.c" -o "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\main.exe" -m64 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include" -I"C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\include\SDL2" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -L"C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\lib" -static-libgcc -m64
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\main.c: In function 'SDL_main':

C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\main.c:3:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
              ^
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\main.c:3:26: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
                          ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\lib/SDL2main.lib(./x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v3-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:17: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Во-первых, уберите *include\* из путей к заголовочному файлу (это в проекте каталог должен подключаться целиком), во-вторых, объявите правильно `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` у себя в коде. Это врядли поможет от ошибки, а наведёт красоту и ясность.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что SDL переопределяет функцию `main`, да и на счет красоты и ясности - вопрос спорный) Но сделал как Вы посоветовали.

Comment: Ну, теперь и ошибочка поменялась. Во-первых, надо подключить WinAPI32 в проект, <s>во-вторых, скорее всего, надо позвать `SDL_main()` из вашего `main()`</s>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079288/im-using-the-sdl-functions-without-the-sdl-main-be-defined-is-that-fine и https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows (то есть я почти угадал)

Comment: Вопрос обновил. Может есть еще идеи решения проблемы.

Comment: Я использую [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) все работает корректно

Comment: Ну, так по ссылке же написано как избавиться от второго `main()`, который `SDL_main()`.

Comment: Да, что-то я сначала не заметил. Спасибо за помощь! Может оформите ответ, чтобы я мог принять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.c:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

make.bat:

```
gcc.exe "main.c" -o "bin\main.exe" -m32 -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include" -I"C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\include" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib32" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib32" -L"C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\dev\lib" -static-libgcc -m32
```

Нормально компилируется и запускается.